# Aggregate identifier must be non-null after applying an event. Make sure the aggregate identifier is initialized at the latest

Tags: axon

I am getting the below error. Axon version 3.3.3

> org.axonframework.eventsourcing.IncompatibleAggregateException:
>   Aggregate identifier must be non-null after applying an event. Make
>   sure the aggregate identifier is initialized at the latest when
>   handling the creation event.

I have created a UserAggregate. It contains 2 events:

- UserCreated
- UpdateUserEvent

I am able to generate the first (UserCreated) event and it was saved in the event store with sequence 0, But while generating the second event I got the above-mentioned error.

Any suggestions on this?

### UserAggregate.java

```
@Aggregate
public class UserAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String id;


    private String email;
    private String password;

    public UserAggregate(String id, String email, String password) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public UserAggregate(CreateUser cmd) {
         AggregateLifecycle.apply(new UserCreated(cmd.getId(), cmd.getEmail(), cmd.getPassword()));
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public void handle(UpdateUserCmd cmd) {
         AggregateLifecycle.apply(new UpdateUserEvent(cmd.getId(), cmd.getEmail(),""));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void userCreated(UserCreated event) {

        System.out.println("new User: email " + event.getEmail() +" Password: "+ event.getPassword());

        setId(event.getId());




    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void updateUserEvent(UpdateUserEvent event) {

        System.out.println("new User: email " + event.getEmail());

        setId(event.getId());




    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public UserAggregate() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am still getting to know Axon but here's how I managed to resolve the issue. Basically what the error is saying is that, when the `UserAggregate` is being instantiated the aggregate identifier (aka Primary Key) must not be null and must have a value.

There sequence of the life-cycle is that

1. It calls a no args constructor
2. It calls the constructor with your initial command, in your case. At this point, your aggregate identifier is still null and we will assign a value in the next step
3. It then calls a `EventSourcingHandler` that handles the event your applied from the previous step

Based on the steps above here's what you need to do:

1. Create a no args constructor

```java
protected UserAggregate() {

}
```

2. Create a constructor which handles your first command:

```java
@CommandHandler
public UserAggregate(CreateUser cmd) {
    AggregateLifecycle.apply(
         new UserCreated(cmd.getId(),cmd.getEmail(),cmd.getPassword()));
}
```

3. Finally add an event sourcing handler to handle the `UserCreated` event

```java
@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(UserCreated userCreated) {

    // this is where we instantiate the aggregate identifier
    this.id = userCreated.getId();
    
    //assign values to other fields
    this.email = userCreated.getEmail();
    this.password = userCreated.getPassword();

}
```

And here's the complete example:

```java
@Aggregate
public class UserAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String id;

    private String password;

    private String email;

    protected UserAggregate() {

    }

    @CommandHandler
    public UserAggregate(CreateUser cmd) {
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(
            new UserCreated(cmd.getId(),cmd.getEmail(),cmd.getPassword()));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(UserCreated userCreated) {

        // this is where we instantiate the aggregate identifier
        this.id = userCreated.getId();

        //assign values to other fields
        this.email = userCreated.getEmail();
        this.password = userCreated.getPassword();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are following the Event Sourcing paradigm for your Aggregates, I'd typically suggest two types of constructors to be present in the code:

1. A default no-arg constructor with no settings in it.
2. One (or more) constructor(s) which handles the 'Aggregate creation command'

In your example I see a third constructor to set `id`, `email` and `password`.
My guess is that this constructor might currently obstruct the `EventSourcedAggregate` implementation for correct validation.

The exception you are receiving can **only** occur if the `@AggregateIdentifier` annotated field **is not** set after the constructor command handler (in your case `UserAggregate(CreateUser)` has ended it's Unit of Work.
Thus, seeing your code, my only hunch is this "wild, unused" constructor which  might obstruct things.

Lastly, I need to recommend you to use a more recent version of Axon.
3.3.3 is already quite far away from the current release, being 4.2.
Additionally, no active development is taking place on Axon 3.x versions.
It is thus wise to upgrade the version, which I assume shouldn't be a big deal as you are still defining your Command Model.

---

**Update**

I've just closed the Framework issue you've opened up. Axon provides entirely different means to tie in to the Message dispatching and handling, giving you cleaner intercept points than (Spring) AOP.

If you following the suggested guidelines to use a `MessageDispatchInterceptor`/`MessageHandlerInterceptor` or the more fine grained option with `HandlerEnhancer`, you can achieve these cross-cutting concerns you are looking for.

As far as logging goes, the framework even provides a `LoggingInterceptor` to do exactly what you need. No AOP needed.

Hope this helps you out Narasimha.

Comment: Hi @Steven, AOP code is causing an issue. Could you please provide any solution or workaround for this issue? as I need AOP code to roll method entry and exit logs automatically.

Comment: Updated the question and dropped the framework issue you created in favor of utilizing Axon's Message Dispatch/Handler Interceptor logic. This provides a cleaner handle than AOP does, thus I would highly recommend to follow that approach.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define the Id attribute in your Aggregate Class
use the axon annotation:

@AggregateIdentifier

Answer (score -1):

Thank you @Steven for the response.

I am able to reproduce this issue with Axon 4.2(latest) version also.
After removing the below AOP code in my project, The issue solved automatically.
Looks like Axon is missing compatible with the AOP feature.

AOP Code:

```
@Around("execution(* com.ms.axonspringboot..*(..))")
    public Object methodInvoke(ProceedingJoinPoint jointPoint) throws Throwable {
        LOGGER.debug(jointPoint.getSignature() + "::: Enters");
        Object obj = jointPoint.proceed();
        LOGGER.debug(jointPoint.getSignature() + "::: Exits");
        return obj;
    }
```

Axon 4.2 version error logs

```
2019-10-07 12:52:41.689  WARN 31736 --- [ault-executor-0] o.a.c.gateway.DefaultCommandGateway      : Command 'com.ms.axonspringboot.commands.UpdateUserCmd' resulted in org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandExecutionException(Aggregate identifier must be non-null after applying an event. Make sure the aggregate identifier is initialized at the latest when handling the creation event.)
2019-10-07 12:52:41.710 ERROR 31736 --- [nio-7070-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.command.AxonServerRemoteCommandHandlingException: An exception was thrown by the remote message handling component: Aggregate identifier must be non-null after applying an event. Make sure the aggregate identifier is initialized at the latest when handling the creation event.
    at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.ErrorCode.lambda$static$8(ErrorCode.java:84) ~[axon-server-connector-4.2.jar:4.2]
    at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.ErrorCode.convert(ErrorCode.java:180) ~[axon-server-connector-4.2.jar:4.2]
```

Comment: Hi @Narasimha, I've updated my original answer and provided feedback on the Axon Framework issue you've created that utilizing (Spring) AOP for cross-cutting concerns within your Aggregate is not the most ideal approach to take. 
You are far better of to using the Handler and Dispatch interceptors, or for more fine grained solutions, HandlerEnhancer(Definition)s.

Would you mind reconsidering marking this as the right answer? As from Axon usage perspective, this answer does not solve the problem you describe. It's rather an update on your original question to point out the problem you have.